# What is selective linking in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, static-linking

In [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-embedded-systems/0596009836/ch04.html) article, I found this line: *The GNU linker uses selective linking, which keeps other unreferenced functions out of the linker’s output image.*

I am not sure what this means exactly. But what I think is, if I include `stdio.h` in my source code, and use only `printf` from that, then the resulting exe contains only code for `printf` extracted from `stdio.c` and other functions defined in that file are discarded.

Is what I say is correct? If not, what does selective linking mean? Also, in the above case, does compiler include entire file, or only the used functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The GNU linker uses selective linking, which keeps other unreferenced functions out of the linker’s output image.

That only applies when linking `.a` files. A `.a` file is a collection of `.o` files. That *selective linking* means it links in only a function rather than the entire `.o` where that function resides.

> if I include `stdio.h` in my source code, and use only `printf` from that, then the resulting exe contains only code for printf extracted from `stdio.c` and other functions defined in that file are discarded.

C standard library functions normally reside in `libc.so`, unless you explicitly link statically. So, either you link `libc.a` and that copies `printf` function into your executable (*selective linking*), or you link `libc.so` and no copy of `printf` is made.

`stdio.c` is only ever used to build `libc.a` and `libc.so`.

---

As @JohannesSchaub-litb mentions in the comment:

- `-ffunction-sections` is needed when compiling `.o` files to take advantage of *selective linking* linker feature:

> Together with a linker garbage collection (linker `--gc-sections` option) these options may lead to smaller statically-linked executables (after stripping).

- `--gc-sections` linker option enables *selective linking*:

> `--gc-sections` decides which input sections are used by examining  symbols and relocations. The section containing the entry symbol  and all sections containing symbols undefined on the command-line  will be kept, as will sections containing symbols referenced by  dynamic objects. Note that when building shared libraries, the  linker must assume that any visible symbol is referenced.

Comment: I thought for .a files it's the entire .o file, but not unrelated .o files. Per-function, really? Don't you need the gc-sections and function-sections flags for that?

Comment: On gcc, -ffunction-sections isn't enabled by default (accordung to the manpage, I think), as it has disadvantages. On ARM-Keil, it's the default, though. Maybe it's advantageous on embedded.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I am confused by "not unrelated .o files". `.a` contains only those `.o` which you put in there.